# Why won't this service start

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have a Windows Service that I'm having some problems getting working.

The pertinent functions are as follows:

( Edited to reflect current )

```
    static void Main()
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            ContinuumService Service = new ContinuumService();
            Service.Start(new Object[] { });

            while (true)
                Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new ContinuumService() 
            };

            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }

    public ContinuumService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
    }
```

My installer is set to 'Allow service to interact with desktop' ( as I cannot seem to get the service to install without this ), and I know that the service is being installed - but is incapable of starting for some reason.

It's my understanding that a service Start command will execute OnStart and wait for that method to complete. Upon completion if the process is still running, the service reports running... If this is skewed please let me know.

The exact error I am getting back from the installer is 'Service '[display name]' ([name]) failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services.'; and from the log that is generated behind the installer, I get an error 1920 with the same message.

In either case - I can't come up with a valid reason why this would be the case. Any advice would be great.

Comment: Permissions?  Go to the service properties and set it to log in as an admin user and see if it starts then.

Comment: What does the StartCommunicator() method do?

Comment: While I don't see any option ( anymore ) in visual studio to configure a service user, I have tried setting the service user in the installer to a variety of options, including a multitude of administrative users, and yielded little difference. In most cases, with 'Allow desktop interaction' disabled, the service will not install...

Comment: The StartCommunicator method opens a named pipe for my UI to reach in over; which runs on a separate thread, and I have tried commenting this out.

Comment: try to start the service manually

Comment: I have. It fails to start in a timely fashion. I can run the service in a debugger and step all the way through to the final 'while' loop in the start method. I'll post an edit with my main, so as not to confuse this functionality with a broken service startup...

Comment: What is the purpose of the while loop?

Comment: The while loop inside of the 'Start' method will run the features of the service - right now it is simply there to keep the service alive so it can report that it is running. If I remove it, the thread stops, and the service stops.

Comment: The service is kept alive by the ServiceBase itself... Remove the loop.

Comment: Then where exactly SHOULD I place my services processing; if not inside of a loop in its own thread...

Comment: Depends on your needs... If it's WCF, open up a ServiceHost. If it's sockets, open up a Socket, etc.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow your meaning... If I don't start another thread and loop inside of it, I only get execution of my OnStart method once... I'm not sure how you're implying that the service is kept alive after it executes OnStart unless there is another task running... Which is effectively all I had done. All irrelevant after edits.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is both the loops and lack of base.OnStart() and base.OnStop() calls. You can start and stop a basic service with no loops, and it will run perpetually. Example basic service that literally does nothing:

```
public class ExampleService : ServiceBase
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new[] { new ExampleService() });
    }

    public ExampleService()
    {
        // Name the Service
        ServiceName = "Example Service";
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);

       // Does nothing
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
    }
}
```

Try implementing this, see that it works, and incrementally add your logic and test.

Comment: While I'm not sure how I accidentally deleted the original base.OnStart(), I've just tried stripping this down to ONLY overrides, and subsequent base calls, with no results...

Comment: I have to disagree - I can run this code no problem on multiple machines in multiple environments. When you say no results, what do you mean? That it doesn't start? That you get an error in the Event Viewer?

Comment: I think your installer is maybe to blame... Try using installutil to install your service instead?

Comment: Well feel free to review my code edits - but this is simply the case. To the best of my knowledge, the service is installing, attempting to start, but failing - 'The service failed to respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.' ( If I attempt to manually start in the 'middle of' my installation )

Comment: While I'd be willing to explore other installer options on any other day; I have successfully installed this service and seen it run once today - in what I would assess as an 'identical' environment - thus my frustrations.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was an issue in my installer. After flipping options off, on, back off, inside out, and every other direction I could, I somehow corrupted the MSI, and had to rebuild it. A full wipe of the original installer project and a fresh build installed the service successfully. This was an issue in Advanced Installer 9.3

Thanks.